# What are this zeros denote?

Tags: networking, netstat

I'm new to Ubuntu and networking , I checked port 6703 and got this:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6703            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5124/java
```

what this zeros denote ?

i got his message when i used it already in use , checked it and got:

```
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    5124 user   71u  IPv4  37584      0t0  TCP *:6703 (LISTEN)
```

and i'm using java code now while i'm using.

Answer (score 1):

It means listen on all available network interfaces.

Comment: i've problem with this port, i cannot bind it beacuse i got message already in use , checked it and got COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    5124 user   71u  IPv4  37584      0t0  TCP *:6703 (LISTEN) and i'm using java code now while i'm using

Comment: Java process 5124 has the port open. Unless you kill that existing process then nothing else can bind that port.

Comment: i'm now submit code with java using this port but after some data i recived it using this port got this error

Comment: Then there is most likely a bug in your java code, whatever that is. Most likely caused by a complete lack of knowledge about how to program sockets.

Comment: You could try `kill -9 5124`, which will forcibly kill java. This will allow the port to bind again.

Comment: should i reboot ubuntu or not  ?

Comment: @willhelmerasmus I am putting my money on him trying ro re-bind a socket after a client has disconnected.

Comment: Why the down votes on this?  The answer is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 1):

The zeroes denote all network interfaces.